# Possible to get apache2 environment variable from command line?

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to check the value of a apache environment variable, `APACHE_LYNX`. It is not accessible with a simple `echo $APACHE_LYNX` command. Is there a way to get access to these environment variables from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's in Apache's environment, you have to get it from Apache. In other words, a job running under the Apache process should be able to access and return the value - in other words a CGI script or other dynamic web content.

For example with PHP you might get it by writing the following to lynx.php in the webroot then browsing to http://server/lynx.php (hypothetical config...)

```
<?php
print(getenv('APACHE_LYNX'));
?>
```

this specific method would need to be adapted to your web server config, supported languages, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for in my LAMP environment. AlmaLinux 8.6. Apache 2.4 and PHP 8.1. Only blank page.